# Yii2 model->created_date is in the future and not returned on queries

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, yii2

I have set the `Yii->application->configuration->timezone` to `UTC` and have model `attributeBehaviors` to insert/update the timestamp using PHP's `time()` method automatically.

The issue, is that the timestamp that is saved to the db is in the future and when I perform a search query for records from today, they aren't being returned if they were created between 10 and midnight as the timestamp is actually tomorrow.

How should I create the record and perform a search query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a difference between PHP any MySQL timezones.

Try to execute the following:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get() . "<br>";
echo Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone . "<br>";
echo Yii::$app->formatter->defaultTimeZone  . "<br>";
echo Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT @@time_zone')->queryScalar()  . "<br>";
echo Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT @@system_time_zone')->queryScalar()  . "<br>";
```

(the query is for MySQL DBMS, if you have another one - the query will be also another)

When you see the difference - you have to set the same timezone in PHP and MySQL ([for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), [for Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$defaultTimeZone-detail))

Comment: I have researched this very conflict and thought I could bypass the conflict was to globally set the Yii/PHP timezone and not use MySQL time functions.  I use the attributeBehaviors to save `time()` which should use the PHP timezone.  Is that correct?  I will run this test tonight.

Comment: This is the response: UTC
UTC
UTC
SYSTEM
GMT+4

Comment: Here is your problem. You create date in UTC, and MySQL think that it is date in UTC+4. You have to [change MySQL timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql) to UTC or set the correct timezone in Yii2 for each connection. To do it open the config.php (where the DB user and password is set) and set timezone like shown [here](https://gist.github.com/SilverFire/6f98d2605a6574bd02f7)

Comment: I found the snippet for Yii2 to modify the MySQL timezone on connect last night.  Now that they are synced, there isn't any issus.  Thanks.